# Map creates undefined items in my array.

Tags: ecmascript-6

Im trying to create an array of all inventors who were born in the 1500.

```
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const inventors2 = inventors.map(
  function(item){
    const yearBorn = item.year;
    if (yearBorn >= 1500 && yearBorn <= 1600) {
    return item;
  }
});

console.log(inventors2);
```

My code sort of works but it returns undefined items in the new array.

```
index-START.html:43 
(12) [undefined, undefined, Object, undefined, Object, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
0
:
undefined
1
:
undefined
2
:
Object
3
:
undefined
4
:
Object
5
:
undefined
6
:
undefined
7
:
undefined
8
:
undefined
9
:
undefined
10
:
undefined
11
:
undefined
length
:
12
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: This is because you return an `item` only if condition is mathed. If not, `map` returns nothing in your code, and the corresponding element in the result array becomes `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method is to use filter:

```
const fifteen = inventors.filter( (item) => {
  const yearBorn = item.year;
  return (yearBorn >= 1500 && yearBorn <= 1600);
});

console.table(fifteen);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter helper for this. `map` helper outputs one value for each element it processes. If nothing matches, leads to `undefined`. Hence `map` helper is not suitable for this usecase. Instead use `filter` helper here.

```
const inventors2 = inventors.filter(inventor => 
  inventor.year >= 1500 && inventor.year <= 1600
);
console.log(inventors2);
```